# Audio and battery status gone after update (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS)

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, power-management, systemd

A couple of days ago I installed standard system updates on a Lenovo Thinkpad T490 with Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS. After rebooting my sound device and the battery status disappeared.

I already managed to manually start pulseaudio (`pulseaudio --start`). After doing so, the sound is temporarily working. However, I am not able to start pulseaudio as a service when booting. I.e., `systemctl --system enable pulseaudio.service` is not working.

Additionally, the battery status is neither showing in the status bar nor in the system settings. Moreover, `upower` is not working. There is a timeout when trying to start the service.

I know the issue sounds like two different problems but both problems came with the same update and might be related to `systemd`.

Here is a (long) list of recently installed updates:

```
2020-11-03:
    linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-48-generic:amd64
    linux-image-5.4.0-48-generic:amd64
    linux-modules-5.4.0-48-generic:amd64
    linux-headers-5.4.0-48-generic:amd64
    linux-headers-5.4.0-48:all
    perl-base:amd64
    perl-modules-5.30:all
    libperl5.30:amd64
    perl:amd64
    man-db:amd64
    libc-bin:amd64
    libgdm1:amd64
    libglib2.0-0:amd64
    libc-bin:amd64
    systemd:amd64
    man-db:amd64
    dbus:amd64
    gir1.2-gdm-1.0:amd64
    gdm3:amd64
    openjdk-11-jre-headless:amd64
    openjdk-11-jre:amd64
    mime-support:all
    hicolor-icon-theme:all
    gnome-menus:amd64
    desktop-file-utils:amd64
    libaccountsservice0:amd64
    accountsservice:amd64
    dbus:amd64
    libc-bin:amd64
    gir1.2-accountsservice-1.0:amd64
    distro-info-data:all
    tzdata:all
    ca-certificates:all
    man-db:amd64
    ca-certificates:all
    libwbclient0:amd64
    samba-libs:amd64
    libsmbclient:amd64
    man-db:amd64
    libc-bin:amd64
    python3-cryptography:amd64
    libmysqlclient21:amd64
    libc-bin:amd64
    
2020-11-04:
    dbus-user-session:amd64
    ubuntu-minimal:amd64
    netplan.io:amd64
    systemd:amd64
    libblkid1:i386
    libgcrypt20:i386
    liblz4-1:i386
    liblzma5:i386
    libpcre2-8-0:i386
    libselinux1:i386
    systemd-timesyncd:amd64
    libsystemd0:amd64
    libsystemd0:i386
    libip4tc2:i386
    libapparmor1:i386
    libgnome-bluetooth13:amd64
    bind9-libs:amd64
    python3-problem-report:all
    libssl1.1:i386
    libargon2-1:i386
    libacl1:i386
    libnetplan0:amd64
    libseccomp2:i386
    libcap2:i386
    python3-apport:all
    grub-common:amd64
    alsa-utils:amd64
    libcap-ng0:i386
    libgmp10:i386
    libp11-kit0:i386
    libaudit1:i386
    libuuid1:i386
    spice-vdagent:amd64
    gnome-bluetooth:amd64
    libdevmapper1.02.1:i386
    libnettle7:i386
    gnome-control-center-faces:all
    libmount1:i386
    libplymouth5:amd64
    libtasn1-6:i386
    build-essential:amd64
    libcryptsetup12:amd64
    libjson-c4:i386
    grub-efi-amd64-bin:amd64
    gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0:amd64
    bind9-host:amd64
    libkmod2:i386
    libhogweed5:i386
    grub2-common:amd64
    grub-pc-bin:amd64
    apport:all
    grub-pc:amd64
    libgnutls30:i386
    libpam0g:i386
    apport-gtk:all
    libcryptsetup12:i386
    bind9-dnsutils:amd64
    grub-efi-amd64-signed:amd64
    dnsutils:all
    systemd:i386
    systemd-timesyncd:i386
    snapd:amd64
    systemd-sysv:amd64
    plymouth:amd64
    libnss-systemd:amd64
    plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:amd64
    libpam-systemd:amd64
    plymouth-label:amd64
    plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo:amd64
    plymouth-theme-spinner:amd64
    install-info:amd64
    desktop-file-utils:amd64
    mime-support:all
    hicolor-icon-theme:all
    gnome-menus:amd64
    libgweather-common:all
    gnome-control-center-data:all
    libglib2.0-0:amd64
    libc-bin:amd64
    libgweather-3-16:amd64
    man-db:amd64
    dbus:amd64
    gnome-control-center:amd64
    gir1.2-gweather-3.0:amd64
    initramfs-tools:all
    libc-bin:amd64
    chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra:amd64
    python3-distupgrade:all
    libasound2-data:all
    ubuntu-release-upgrader-core:all
    libudev1:amd64
    libudev1:i386
    libasound2:amd64
    ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk:all
    libatopology2:amd64
    udev:amd64
    systemd:i386
    man-db:amd64
    libc-bin:amd64
    initramfs-tools:all
    alsa-base:all
    alsa-base:all
    pulseaudio:amd64
    systemd:i386
    man-db:amd64
    dbus:amd64
    
2020-11-05:
    liburl-dispatcher1:amd64
    libfcitx-utils0:amd64
    libbamf3-2:amd64
    libindicator3-7:amd64
    libfcitx-gclient1:amd64
    libunity-gtk2-parser0:amd64
    libido3-0.1-0:amd64
    libunity-gtk3-parser0:amd64
    jayatana:amd64
    libgnome-panel0:amd64
    liblightdm-gobject-1-0:amd64
    indicator-common:all
    gnome-screensaver:amd64
    accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas:all
    ubuntu-touch-sounds:all
    indicator-application:amd64
    indicator-printers:amd64
    indicator-applet:amd64
    desktop-file-utils:amd64
    mime-support:all
    hicolor-icon-theme:all
    gnome-menus:amd64
    unity-settings-daemon-schemas:all
    unity-gtk-module-common:all
    indicator-sound:amd64
    indicator-power:amd64
    indicator-messages:amd64
    indicator-keyboard:amd64
    indicator-datetime:amd64
    indicator-bluetooth:amd64
    indicator-appmenu:amd64
    libglib2.0-0:amd64
    libc-bin:amd64
    unity-gtk2-module:amd64
    man-db:amd64
    indicator-session:amd64
    unity-gtk3-module:amd64
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Exactly which packages were updated?  You can review your apt logs if you don't remember

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I inserted the list of updated packages in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problems. As suspected, `systemd` was the actual problem. After reinstalling it the according sound and battery services were running correctly again.

Comment: On my T470s after update to ubuntu 20.04.1 the battery and sound indicator was gone and strangely enough the package "systemd:386" was installed. I replaced it with "systemd" and everything ran again as before. Thanks for your hints!